# Analyzing dynamic programming solutions to different maximum subarray problems

Tags: python, algorithm, dynamic-programming, clrs

I was trying out some dynamic programming problems. I came across the following problems:

**1. Maximum (consecutive) subset-sum**
Finding the maximum sum of any consecutive set of elements in the given input array.
One possible solution is as follows:

```
def max_subarray_sum(arr):
    curr_sum = arr[0]
    max_so_far = arr[0]

    for num in arr[1:]:
        curr_sum = max(num, curr_sum + num)
        max_so_far = max(curr_sum, max_so_far)
    return max_so_far
```

**2. Maximum non-adjacent elements subset-sum**
Given an array of integers, find the subset of non-adjacent elements with the maximum sum. Calculate the sum of that subset. [hackerrank link](https://www.hackerrank.com/challenges/max-array-sum/problem)
One possible solution in python is as follows:

```
def maxSubsetSum(arr): 
    second_last_max_sum = arr[0]  
    last_max_sum = max(arr[0], arr[1])
    for num in arr[2:]: 
        curr_max_sum = max(num, last_max_sum, second_last_max_sum + num)
        second_last_max_sum = last_max_sum
        last_max_sum = curr_max_sum
    return last_max_sum
```

The solution to the first problem involves two `max()`, while that for the second involves single `max()`. So, I was guessing if I can somehow build logic with just single `max()` for the first problem, say by changing arguments to that single `max()` like for the second problem.

**Q1.** After considerable pondering, I came to the conclusion that I cannot because of the constraint in the first problem: sub-array need to be formed by consecutive numbers. Am I right with this?

**Q2.** Also, can I generalize this further, that is, what **"kinds"** of problems can be solved with just single `max()` and which kinds of problems require more than one `max()`? Or in other words, what are the **"characteristics"** of constraints on subarray that can be solved in single `max()` and of those that need at least two `max()`?

Comment: I think by `max()` you are referring to comparison operations in general. For Q2, there are a large number of problems where the time complexity analysis focuses on the number of comparisons. However they only look at asymptotic numbers and whether you have a single or two comparisons in a for-loop is irrelevant. I don't think there is any analysis on these "characteristics" since this does not seem to have any theoretical significance.

Comment: why is it important? both `max`-es in the first problem are over 2 elements and thus have constant complexity. Eliminating one of them won't change the big-O

Comment: btw, the first solution doesn't seem right

Comment: I was just thinking in logical (or better, logic building) point of view and not from the point of view of time complexity.